# "Variable Undeclared" error when compiling to iOS Device, but not for Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, compiler-errors

I have an custom UIVIewController that is the base class for other controllers and has an instance of a custom UIView variable that is accessed by inherited the classes.

BaseViewController.h

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *_vwHeader;
}

@end
```

BaseViewController.m

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
@implementation BaseViewController

-(void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    _vwHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

CustomViewController.h

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
@interface CustomViewController : BaseViewController

@end
```

CustomViewController.m

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"
@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    [_vwHeader setHidden:NO];
}

@end
```

The problem is that when I am running it on the simulator everything works perfectly fine, but when I change to the device I have an error on the `[_vwHeader setHidden:NO];` line which says: `'_vwHeader' undeclared (first use in this function)`

I already tried to do:

- Comment this line of code, but then it gives me an error in another class using a variable from the base class the same way (It only returns one error at a time), so it seems that it is not an specific error in the view or the controller class as the error occurs in other clases with different types, such as `UIView` and `NSObject` types
- Change target compiler configuration, such as: architectures (all of them), base sdk (all above 4.0) didn't change anything

What seem to solve the problem, but not completely

- Creating a property for `_vwHeader` and accessing it by `self._vwHeader` or `super._vwHeader` seems to work, but having to create a property just to access a variable does not make me confortable, specially because I would have to do it for all variables in the same situation inside my project.
- **changed C/C++ compiler version: using `Apple LLVM Compiler 2.1` makes the compilation error goes away, but gives a bunch of other problems with other libraries being used in the project. So, it is not a definitive solution, but might be a clue of what the problem is.**

EDIT:

I tried to create another variable that is not a pointer, a `BOOL` instead of the `UIView *`  and then used it in the inherited class: the problem also occurs

EDIT (2):

I have no properties whatsoever in any of my classes and I still get the error. 
I just added the properties for test porpouses, to see if a property in a parent class caused the same behaviour, and apparently it doesn't.
Something that is also weird is that when I get the error in the variable, I checked with my intellisense and it finds it...

Comment: Maybe check something is going on with your xcode schemas ie BaseViewController.m is ticked in the target membership panel of xcode

Comment: Can you post a complete Xcode project that reproduces this error?

Comment: @vocaro sorry, It is happening in one that is has a lot of company property and I have no idea of how to reproduce it in others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to refer to an instance variable within any object other than `self`, including `super`, you must use the structure pointer operator (`->`). The default scope of an instance variable is protected, which means it can only be accessed within the class it is defined in or a subclass of that class. Since `CustomViewController` is a subclass of `BaseViewController`, this scope is sufficient to access the variable using `self->_vwHeader`, but if the second class you were trying to do this from is not a subclass you will also need to change the scope to either `@public` or `@package`.

In summary, change your method call to:

```
[self->_vwHeader setHidden:NO];
```

and it should work for any subclasses of the base view controller.

Comment: Ok, now my only question is why sometimes it works? What my project has that makes this error to be raised that others don't?

Comment: and also why does this error happens when compiling for the device only? and not for simulator...

Comment: Just to make it clear, the structure pointer operator above did make the project compile, I just want to know what my cause the compiler error in this project and not in others, and also why only when compiling for devices

Comment: I am no super expert on Objective-C, but this answer has me completely baffled - I have never seen anyone access ivars through structure pointer variables. Are you sure that is a good idea?

Comment: @Monolo See [Referring to Instance Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-88281). It is required when accessing a variable directly from objects other than the receiver, and optional otherwise. `self->ivar` is compiled exactly the same as `ivar`.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw You're right, thanks for the link. Happy to learn something new. That said, my personal preference on encapsulation is that outside objects should keep their dirty little fingers off my ivars :-) If they want my ivars, they can go the proper way through the accessors that I will provide if I think they should have access...

Comment: This is actually a bug in GCC 4.2 (as distributed with current Xcode) when you use ivar synthesis. It works in LLVM GCC 4.2.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, but once again, just to make it clear, the structure pointer operator above did make the project compile, but why? and why only for devices? Is it a bug in the compiler? And also what causes this bug, as it does not happen in all variables?

Answer (score 2):

Do a clean and build, and also make sure you are not specifying a specific framework search path in the build settings. If you leave it empty you should get the correct libraries.
well I don't know, should work.

BaseViewController.h

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *_vwHeader;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIView *_vwHeader;
@end
```

BaseViewController.m

```
@synthesize _vwHeader;
```

CustomViewController.m

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"
@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    [self._vwHeader setHidden:NO];
}
```

@end

Comment: I have done several clean and build, even after closing and re-opening XCode. Also, my search paths are empty already

Comment: you can try to add the @public declaration before it, I thought that was default, but may not be for some reason.

Comment: @public, @protected and the other modifiers didn't work either

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, I have already tried to create a property. but that does not solve the problem, just mask it up, as it happens all over my project "What seem to solve the problem, but not completely

Creating a property for _vwHeader and accessing it by self._vwHeader or super._vwHeader seems to work, but having to create a property just to access a variable does not make me confortable, specially because I would have to do it for all variables in the same situation inside my project."

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem as you. In my case the reason was (strangely!) wrong synthesization of properties in subclass.

Example:

In .h file of subclass you have following declaration

```
BOOL _flag;
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL flag;
```

while in you synthesize the property in the wrong way:

```
@synthesize flag;
```

instead of

```
@synthesize flag = _flag;
```

Strangely, the compiler does not complain about the wrong synthesization (the properties even work fine!), but raises an error, when I try to access protected fields declared in base class.

---

Detailed explanation

Here is what my code look like

I have base class (excerpt):

```
@interface BaseEditionModalController : NSObject 
{
    DataContext *_dataContext;
}
```

And I have subclass of it (excerpt):

```
@interface LocationModalController : BaseEditionModalController
{
    MCLocation *_readLocation;

    LocationCommModel *_oldLocationCommModel;   
}

//This is MCLocation for reading only - from the main application context
@property (nonatomic, retain) MCLocation *readLocation;

@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationCommModel *oldLocationCommModel;

@end
```

And in the LocationModalController.m I have following wrong declarations:

```
@implementation LocationModalController

@synthesize readLocation;
@synthesize oldLocationCommModel;
```

Trying to access _dataContext in LocationModalController produced the error that _dataContext is undeclared.

Changing the synthesization of properties to:

```
@implementation LocationModalController

@synthesize readLocation = _readLocation;
@synthesize oldLocationCommModel = _oldLocationCommModel;
```

MAGICALLY SOLVES THE PROBLEM!

Regards

Comment: But he problem is that I have no properties... Did you have the problem accessing `_dataContext` if you remove all properties and `syntesize`s? Because that is what is happening to me :(

Comment: No, when I removed the synthesizes and properties, I was able to access _dataContext without error - that was what led me to the solution.

I suggest you looking for some other code errors in your class - maybe that's the case.

Comment: It's not a "wrong synthesization"; GCC 4.2 does ivar synthesis (so you don't need to pollute header files with ivars) but with a couple of bugs. The first is that you need to use `self->` to access ivars of base classes, and the second is that GDB doesn't know about them so can't print them (argh!).

Answer (score 1):

I just stumble upon your method declaration

```
-(void)loadView { ... }
```

In a view the first point you can rely that everything is fully initialized is after -(void)viewDidLoad was called. Maybe your code works on the simulator because your Mac is fast enough to cope this speed issue - but your mobile device isn't.

Maybe try this coding:

**Your BaseViewController.h file:**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *_vwHeader;
}
@end
```

**Your BaseViewController.m file:**

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
@implementation BaseViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _vwHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

**Your CustomViewController.h file:**

```
@interface CustomViewController : BaseViewController {
}
@end
```

**Your CustomViewController.m file:**

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_vwHeader setHidden:NO];
}
```

Now your CustomViewController can rely on every instance variable in BaseViewController is correctly instantiated.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't say "it works on the simulator and not in the device", I said it didn't compile at all for the device

Answer (score 1):

The error says that _vwHeader undeclared.
So try by modifying the code in:

CustomViewController.m

```
    #import "CustomViewController.h"
    @implementation CustomViewController

    - (void)loadView
    {
        [super loadView];
        if(!_vwHeader)
        {
           _vwHeader = [[UIView alloc]init];
        }
        [_vwHeader setHidden:NO];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: as it is not a runtime error, it a compilation one, it did not solve the problem and the error is now happening in the `if(!_vwHeader)` line

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that when you compile for target and for simulation the data members are either protected or private. Probably for target are private by default and this seems to cause the problem. Try out playing with the `@private` and `@protected` keywords.

However, I strongly suggest that you use properties even between your super/sub-classes. Having a complex structure is a bit hard to debug. Setting up a property will transfer the access to the data through the getter/setter methods (a breakpoint on `@synthesize` also works) and you will be able to see in the call stack who is accessing what.

Especially, the syntax `@synthesize propertyName = prefixDataNameSufix;` allows you to easily adjust your class interface style without having to modify your coding habits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it turns out that I did not remove an unused iVar/property in the SUBCLASS. Let's call it `session`. I removed `_session` from the iVar but I forgot to remove it from the properties, then in the .m file I had this `synthesize session = _session`. Once I removed them all, I can compile for iOS device without problems.

If you think your superclass is fine, look into your subclass, check your iVars and properties and synthesize section in the .m file

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.

In my case, I was relying on ivar synthesis of a property. That is, I did NOT declare **UITextView *textView_**, but I did **@synthesize textView = textView_;**

This builds fine on my iOS Simulator. However, my iOS device build fails, regardless of whether I use llvm or gcc.

When I add the declaration back to my interface:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : BaseTableViewController {
    @private
    UITextView *textView_; // this line is important!
}
```

Everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

See the answer from tc above. This is a bug in the compiler shipped with sdk 4.2.
Specifically I have seen the same error and if on the same machine I have sdk 4.2 and sdk 4.3 installed the error disappears (even if I compile for 4.2).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue after upgrading their tools and devices to iOS10, I had it and found that declaring them as weak, nonatomic in the .h file was the issue. I had never encountered this when doing so before but after removing (weak, nonatomic) from the property declaration, everything worked fine again.